# How to dynamically change the sheet type theme during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, matplotlib-widget

I am working on dynamically changing matplotlib style sheet during runtime. I have initialized a class for matplotlib widget and chosen two styles from matplotlib style sheet reference - let's say default and dark_background styles.

Refer link for matplotlib style sheet : https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html.

I have initialized a push button configured to switch between the two styles.

When the button is toggled, it gets detected. I have a function with input from the push button toggle and its input is used to enable the matplotlib style sheet.

When the code is executed, when I toggle the push button, the matplotlib style sheet change does not apply.

Here is the code snippet for reference:

```
def style_select(self):
    if self.style == "dark":
        plt.style.use('dark_background')
    else:
        plt.style.use('default')
    self.canvas.draw()
    pass
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is impossible to answer your question. Please add code snippers of what you are doing. Read here to understand what's the best way to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you need to place your cutom mplstyle file in the same directory where Matplotlib stores its mplstyle files:`./Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib`
then set stylesheet in your code using the cutom mplstyle file name without its extension: `plt.style.use('mystyle')`

Answer (score 0):

plt.style.use() works only when the widget class is first instanciated (when the plot/figure is initially created). it works also when a subplot is added. you change the color scheme using the following instead for the current object:

```
*.canvas.figure.set_edgecolor("white")
*.canvas.figure.set_facecolor("white")
*.canvas.figure.axes.axe.set_facecolor("white")

*.canvas.figure.set_edgecolor("black")
*.canvas.figure.set_facecolor("black")
*.canvas.figure.axes.axe.set_facecolor("black")
```